# Mongodb pool destroyed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sometimes the `mongod` service restarts on server and it makes the `mongoose` to throw an exception:

```sh
MongoError: pool destroyed
    at Pool.write (node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:844:8)
```

Is there a way to automatically detect that the pool has been destroyed and force the server to do a reconnection or a restart?

I mean, in the code there are lots of operations against db and would be a disaster if I should check every operation to db in order to see if connection is still alive, so I'm looking for a solution that could monitor the connection and catch all `pool destroyed` errors, so I could force the server to restart.